# Foursquare API /lists/USER_ID/tips doesn't include any groups for todo or done

Tags: foursquare

Is there any way to get out the list of users who have done/todo'd the dones and todos? The documentation implies that the todo and done fields should contain both a count and an array of these groups, but in practice while I am getting non-zero counts, the groups array is always empty for the deprecated /users/USER_ID/tips call and nonexistent in the /lists/USER_ID/tips call (and empty in other places it might be, like listItems.items.tip.listed.groups.items of type "dones", even when the count is nonzero).

I'm trying to replace a (presumably deprecated) call I have in compiled code that gives me the right output so I know such a call must exist somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tips detail endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/tips) to get more information about the tip, including likes/todos.

Comment: It turned out this was what the compiled code was doing. I was hoping there would be another way but it's what I ended up doing.